# keeping track of text based hangman game in an output file

Tags: java, stringtokenizer, file-writing

Long story short, gameplayWord is a word that was randomly determined from a list of words for a hangman game read from (in this case the easy words file). easyContentList is an ArrayList of all the data in that file. The file is 2 columns, first col - the words that can be used, 2nd - a number representing how many times the word was used. (0 in the initial file) I need to keep track of this number based on each iteration of the game.
easyFileUpdateList is a String ArrayList declared at the class level. 
Problem is this basically doesn't work:

```
public void updateEasyFile(String gameplayWord, ArrayList<String> easyContentList) {

    Integer used = 0; // represents used word count
    String strUsed = ""; 

    for (int i = 0; i < easyContentList.size() - 1; i++) {
        String oneLine;
        oneLine = easyContentList.get(i);
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(oneLine);

        String firstToken = tokenizer.nextToken();

        if (firstToken.equals(gameplayWord)) {
            used = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            used++;
            strUsed = used.toString();
            easyFileUpdateList.add(gameplayWord + "    " + strUsed + "    " + "TODO");
        }
        if (!firstToken.equals(tokenizer.nextToken())) // add the first token of every line except the first
            easyFileUpdateList.add(oneLine);        
    }

    try {

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("hmeasy.txt")));

        for (String oneLine : easyFileUpdateList) {
            printWriter.println(oneLine);
        }
        printWriter.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        fnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

Thank you, I will look into hash sets. Let me clarify a little more, I'm still not following completely.

Correct, the file will be as you said, so if the words are dog, cat, and fog the file will look like:

```
dog    0
cat    0
fog    0
```

There is a 3rd column of zeros, which is what the TODO is for but I'll worry about that later.

You are correct the problem that I am having is it is just adding a new entry with the word and then a 1 in the 2nd column. So if fog is randomly picked 3 times in a row and this method is executed it will say

```
dog    0
cat    0
fog    1
dog    0
cat    0
fog    1
fog    1
dog    0
cat    0
fog    1
fog    1
fog    1
```

what I'm looking for is:
 first round:

```
dog   0
cat   0 
fog   1
```

2nd round:

```
dog   0
cat   0
fog   2
```

etc...

I need to update the number in the file each time the word is randomly chosen.

Comment: Basically, what does it do?  Can the game be played?  Does it change the file at all when it is?

Answer (score 0):

Near as I can tell if your hmeasy.txt file looks like this:

```
 firstGamePlayWord    0
 secondGamePlayWord    0
```

And if the first entry is played it will soon look like this:

```
 firstGamePlayWord    0
 secondGamePlayWord    0
 firstGamePlayWord    1    TODO
```

Which, I suspect, is not what you want.  It's doing this because you use this line:

```
easyFileUpdateList.add(gameplayWord + "    " + strUsed + "    " + "TODO");
```

since this is an `ArrayList` `add()` just tacks that line at the end.

I could tell you to instead use `set()` with the `i` you worked so hard to find but that would be encouraging a bad design.  You should stop using `ArrayList` for this.  It wasn't designed for lookups.

Instead I encourage you to look at using a `LinkedHashSet<String, Integer>`.  No need to tokenize, lookups will be fast, and everything will be in the same order it was added.

When trying to find the right data structure in java I look at this:
[image]

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this site I posted my response to this in an answer, not sure if I did that right..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I will look into hash sets. Let me clarify a little more, I'm still not following completely.

Correct, the file will be as you said, so if the words are dog, cat, and fog the file will look like:

```
dog    0
cat    0
fog    0
```

There is a 3rd column of zeros, which is what the TODO is for but I'll worry about that later.

You are correct the problem that I am having is it is just adding a new entry with the word and then a 1 in the 2nd column. So if fog is randomly picked 3 times in a row and this method is executed it will say

```
dog    0
cat    0
fog    1
dog    0
cat    0
fog    1
fog    1
dog    0
cat    0
fog    1
fog    1
fog    1
```

what I'm looking for is:
 first round:

```
dog   0
cat   0 
fog   1
```

2nd round:

```
dog   0
cat   0
fog   2
```

etc...

I need to update the number in the file each time the word is randomly chosen.

Comment: Well you are allowed to answer your own question.  But that's for when you've figured out an answer and want to share it.  With this what you should do is click the edit link on your question and add an update.  I did it for you just to show you how.  Don't be afraid to edit your questions heavily to make them clear. You can delete this answer now.